# Is web site in-scope for PCI even though it redirects to a 3rd-party for card transaction?

Tags: pci-scope

Even though the web site never sees the cardholder data or sensitive authentication data in the clear, and never has access to the encryption keys, I would think the web site *is* in-scope because it could affect the security of the data.  If the web site is hacked and changes the redirect to go to a hacker site, data can then be stolen.

In the case I am working now, the web site is owned by a service provider that a merchant is working with.  The service provider is not the 3rd party that deals with the card data.  If I am correct it leads to a slightly weird situation where there is no CDE (cardholder data environment) at the service provider and they only have this one web server that is in-scope.  Although there is a question of whether other servers on the same network "segment" as the web server should get pulled in-scope too, but that is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are still in scope, although a lower level of compliance may apply to you. Read the following:

> Q2: To whom does the PCI DSS apply?
>
> A: The PCI DSS applies to ANY organization, regardless of size or number of transactions, that accepts, transmits or stores any cardholder data.
>
> *Source:* [To Whom does PCI DSS apply?](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/#2)

You may qualify for one of the less restrictive levels of PCI-DSS.  To find out, check this link: [Which SAQ is appropriate for me?](https://www.mwrinfosecurity.com/our-thinking/pci-compliance-which-saq-is-right-for-me/)

Here is a good reference to get you started on your own compliance: [ComplianceGuide.org](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/the-pci-basicsquick-guide-what-do-small-merchants-need-to-do-to-achieve-pci-compliance/).

Comment: In the specific case I am looking at, a full ROC is required for the service provider. If a ROC were not required SAQ-A would fit the bill. There is an FAQ that indicates that when a ROC is needed, if a particular SAQ would have otherwise fit, that SAQ can guide which requirements in the ROC are relevant or not-applicable.  However SAQ-A is only for merchants, so doesn't seem to help me.